# ReferenceError: <module> is not defined when running Jasmine unit tests in Karma

Tags: angularjs

I am getting a failed test with the error `ReferenceError: dmeApp is not defined`. Do I need to inject `dmeApp` into the test? I'm following a tutorial I found here: http://andyshora.com/unit-testing-best-practices-angularjs.html

app.js:

```
angular.module('dmeApp', ['ngRoute', 'dmeApp.library'])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/library', {
      templateUrl: 'library.html',
      controller: 'LibraryController',
    })
    .when('/styleguide', {
      templateUrl: 'styleguide.html',
    })
    .otherwise({
      templateUrl: 'front.html',
    });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])

.controller('NavController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.linkIsActive = function(viewLocation) {
    return viewLocation === $location.path();
  };
}]);
```

app.spec.js:

```
describe('Header Navigation', function() {
  beforeEach(angular.module('dmeApp'));

  it('should have a NavController defined', function() {
    expect(dmeApp.NavController).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

And my Karma config (in Gruntfile.js):

```
/**
 * Our Karma configuration.
 */
 karma: {
  options: {
    files: [
      '<%= vendor_files.js %>',
      '<%= vendor_files.offline_js %>', // angular is added here
      '<%= vendor_files.test_js %>', // angular-mock is added here
      'src/**/*.js', // all app files and specs are added here
    ],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],        
  },
  dev: {
    reporters: 'dots',
    background: true,
  },
  continuous: {
    singleRun: true,
  },
 },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the spec.js in the beforeEach try something like:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {

var dmeAppNavController = $injector.get('dmeApp.NavController');

...
}
```

then you can use dmeAppNavController in the testcases.

imho almost always a good idea to use the $injector in the test cases